# Problem of two scales in a corridor

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

There are two scales: one of length $z$ and the other of $y$. these scales is placed in a
row so that their ends are each supported on opposite walls of the
hall and that the scales intersect. Also scales foot from the same level of
corridor.

*Find the height $h$ of the intersection of scales in function of the corridor has a length $x <\min (y,z) $. (h=f(x))*

[image: plan]

Comment: Split $x$ into $w$ and $x-w$, then find some similar triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = a + b$ where $a$ is the length to the left of $h$ and $b$ is the length to the right of $h$

From similarity on the left triangle, we have
$$
\frac{b}{h} = \frac{a+b}{y}
$$
and for the triangle on the right we have
$$
\frac{a}{h} = \frac{a+b}{z}
$$
Dividing these two equalities, you get 
$$
\frac{a}{b} = \frac{y}{z}
$$
From the first equality, you have
$$
h = y\times \frac{b}{a+b}
$$
Notice that 
$$
\frac{b}{a+b} = \frac{z}{y+z}
$$
which should help you conclude that 
$$
h = \frac{yz}{y+z}.
$$

Comment: this is not true because $h$ dependent of the lenght of corridor $x $

Comment: @Hamza, no the height $h$ is not dependent on the length $x$. If you draw the picture several times with the same values of $y$ and $z$ you will see that $h$ is always the same. (Assuming that you mean that $y$ and $z$ are perpendicular to $x$ as drawn in the picture.)

Comment: exuse me the picture isn't clear $y $ and $z $ denote the lenght of scales not the hight of walls i will fix it